# how to get current url in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

my url is like this `http://www.dynamo-client-test2.com/#!/home` for home page

```
 http://www.dynamo-client-test2.com/#!/about-us
```

for about us page

Now, i want slider on home page only not in about us page.
i have written in header.html following:

```
<?php         if(is_home() || is_front_page()){?>
    <?php include_once(TEMPLATEPATH . '/slider.php'); ?>
    <?php }?>
```

Then slider will be shown in all pages.
I want only in home page.
so what to do ?
please help me as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From http://wordpress.org/support/topic/is_home-php-rule-not-working-correctly

> In WordPress parlance, Home refers to the Blog Posts Index (which is why is_home() returns true on blog post archive pages). The Site Front Page is referred to as Front Page.
>
> So, if you want to test conditionally for your Site Front Page, then use is_front_page().

Comment: hello @floris <?php
global $paged;

echo $paged;
if ( is_home() && '1' > $paged ) {
 include_once(TEMPLATEPATH . '/slider.php');} else {
  echo "bad";
}
?>this is not working

Comment: What does "is not working" mean in this case. You need to test for `is_front_page()` per the post I copied, NOT `is_home()`. Confusing, I know...

Comment: <?php
global $paged;
if ( is_front_page() && '1' > $paged ) {
 include_once(TEMPLATEPATH . '/slider.php');} else {
  echo "nooooooooooooooooooo";
}
?>in all pages slider is coming :( @floris

Comment: Lets try something else. Can you get the _exact_ example show [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/header-menu-item-to-appear-only-home-page)  to work for you?

Comment: <?php if ( is_front_page() ) { 
include_once(TEMPLATEPATH . '/slider.php');
 } ?>I had tried this. but slider is displaying on all pages including home page. @floris

Answer (score 0):

1. Is header.php (no .html).
2. Isn't necesarry to use conditional here, because in your template root you can make a file with home.php or index.php name which is used only by frontpage/homepage.
3. If you want to use is_homepage/front_page() again you must verify your loop file for errors.

Comment: ya its header.php.so i have to make home.php in template root?in home.php what content should i place?@teo

Comment: index.php is there in my template root

Comment: Sorry for the long time of waiting... The home.php will be similary to index.php but will contain your slide where you want to put it on page.

Comment: If a static front page has not been set, then WordPress looks for a template file called home.php and uses it to generate the requested page.

Comment: So you must create home.php page.

Comment: If home.php is missing, WordPress looks for a file called index.php in the active theme's directory, and uses that template to generate the page.

Comment: Similary to that, you can make different looks for category (create a file named category.php), for search (search.php), for articles (single.php), for pages (page.php) etc (you will find all posibilities at link above).

Comment: Alternative solution: Template file used to render the Site Front Page, whether the front page displays the Blog Posts Index or a static page. The Front Page template takes precedence over the Blog Posts Index (Home) template.

        front-page.php - Used for both Your latest posts or A static page as set in the Front page displays section of Settings -> Reading
        Page display rules - When Front page is set in the Front page displays section of Settings -> Reading
        Home Page display rules - When Posts page is set in the Front page displays section of Settings -> Reading.

Comment: So, you can make front-page.php too for that.

Comment: index.php is a general page, so if you'll create home.php or front-page.php automatically these will be used as front page. More info in codex. I recommend you to create home.php, no front-page.php, but is your decision.